# BRIEF descriptor and matlab code

Tags: computer-vision

i want to know more about brief descriptor algorithm and matlab code for this.
the points copmare with another what choice them. e.g. 128 point at patch how are choose.?
thanks

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you're asking. Please re-state the question... and check the spelling and grammar to make sure it captures your intent.